# Manifest references file 'Bing.Maps.dll' which is not part of the payload

Tags: manifest, bing-maps, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Error   1   Manifest references file 'Bing.Maps.dll' which is not part of the payload.  C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\Applicationxx\Applicationxx\Package.appxmanifest   Application7

I added this into a existing Metro application and its giving me that error, anyone has solution to it?

Comment: Clearly it's telling you that there's a reference to Bing.Maps.dll, which isn't included in the application package. If you're writing this application, make sure you have referenced Bing.Maps correctly and that it's being added to the output package.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the properties of the project and under Build, you will see Platform Target. Choose either *x64* or *x86* instead of *Any CPU* and it should be solved.

~Guo Hong

Answer (score 2):

To correctly reference Bing Maps for a Metro app...

Go to: Project -> Add Reference -> Windows -> Extensions

Now, select *both* the "Bing Maps for ..." and also "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package"

If you don't select the 2nd package, things will seem to be fine until you try to actually deploy your app.