# While creating package for UWP with sideloading option getting error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to create package for UWP with sideloading option but getting following error...visual studio 2017

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Manifest references file 'Assets\Icon\StoreLogo.png' which is not part of the payload.  Versatilis.Shell.UWP    E:\AppName.UWP\Package.appxmanifest 8

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Manifest references file 'Assets\Icon\Square150x150Logo.png' which is not part of the payload.  Versatilis.Shell.UWP    E:\AppName.UWP\Package.appxmanifest   18

Comment: Why aren’t you using VS2019?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when building universal app for the store: "Manifest references file 'MyAppName.dll' which is not part of the payload."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697674/error-when-building-universal-app-for-the-store-manifest-references-file-myap)